# From which Russian-American Company ship did Osip Volkov defect to Mexico?

Tags: russia, mexico, california

Several books and articles indicate that Osip Volkov defected from a Russian ship at Monterey around 1815, midway through the Mexican War of Independence. Naturalized as Jose Antonio Bolcof, he served as alcalde of Branciforte. The Russian-American Company had a royal monopoly on the fur trade in America. What was the ship on which Volkov arrived in California?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rancho_San_Agustin) article refers to him as a fur trader and I thought that adding that derail made sense of your reference to the Russian-American Company having a royal monopoly on the fur trade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to pg 317 of the Book [California Through Russian Eyes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0870624210), by James R Gibson,

> ...while hunting sea otters from the *Ilmena*, he either jumped ship or
>   was captured by a Spanish patrol.

The *Ilmena* is listed as 'purchased from the Americans' on the [Russia-America Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian-American_Company) wiki page.

So there's your ship name, and yes he was employed in the fur trade.