# Who accompanied Canónigo Fernández to Mexico City in 1822?

Tags: government, colonial-america, mexico, california

After Iturbide became President of an independent Mexico, the Canónigo Don Agustín Fernández de San Vicente was sent to Alta California to support the transition from Spanish rule and to relieve the last Spanish governor, Pablo Vicente de Solá. He met with officials throughout the state, [including those at Fort Ross](http://www.fortross.org/lib/163/diary-of-the-journey-of-fray-mariano-payeras.pdf). At the end of 1822, Canónigo Fernández and ex-governor Solá traveled to Mexico City via San Diego, Tepic, and Guadalajara. Several others from California seem to have accompanied them; who were these other members of the party?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the names of two individuals reported to have accompanied Fernandez and Sola on this trip: Gomez and Bolcof.

From Bancroft ([History of California](https://books.google.com/books?id=lgETAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA450&dq=canonigo%20Fernandez%201822&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju9JfJ9b3WAhXM6YMKHbKCBM8Q6AEIPDAD#v=onepage&q=canonigo%20Fernandez%201822&f=true) pg 470):

> On the *San Carlos* besides the canon sailed Sola and **Lieutenant Manuel
>   Gomez** who left the artillery force of California to the command of
>   Ramirez

Later in the chapter (pg. 479), while discussing foreigners in California, Bancroft drops another name:

> **Jose Bolcof** the Russian was married this year to Candida Castro and
>   *possibly* he was the Russian who accompanied the canonigo to Mexico

Bancroft seems hesitant in this connection, but it is repeated in a (more) recent publication  [Visit of the Russian Warship Apollo to California
 in 1822-1823](http://www.militarymuseum.org/Apollo.pdf)(from  Southern California Quarterly)

> The visiting representative, the Canónigo Agustín Fernández de San 
>   Vicente, had departed Monterey on November 22 aboard the Imperial 
>   Mexican Man-of-War San Carlos, taking with him not only ex-gover-  nor
>   Pablo Vicente de Sola but apparently the principal Russian-Span-  ish
>   translator available to the Californians, José Antonio Bolcof (Osip 
>   Volkov)

and of course we are familiar with Bolcof from:

- [who-was-the-first-foreigner-to-be-naturalized-as-a-mexican-citizen-in-alta-calif](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34097/who-was-the-first-foreigner-to-be-naturalized-as-a-mexican-citizen-in-alta-calif)
- [from-which-russian-american-company-ship-did-osip-volkov-defect-to-mexico](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/33410/from-which-russian-american-company-ship-did-osip-volkov-defect-to-mexico)